# Cannot access phpmyadmin after installing mod_pagespeed on centos

Tags: phpmyadmin, centos7, mod-pagespeed

OS: centos 7.2
Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)

After install pagespeed module, I got error 404 when access http://myip/phpmyadmin
I cannot find phpmyadmin at /usr/share/phpmyadmin anymore

And this is log when show locate phpmyadmin:

```
[root@localhost ~]# locate phpmyadmin
/var/cache/mod_pagespeed/prop_page/http,3A/,2F112.78.1.23/phpmyadmin
/var/cache/mod_pagespeed/prop_page/http,3A/,2F112.78.1.23/phpmyadmin/_-l8wrv0-x1,40Desktop,40beacon_cohort,
/var/cache/mod_pagespeed/rname/ce_-l8wrv0-x10oaQd5TPG4/http,3A/,2F112.78.1.23/phpmyadmin
/var/cache/mod_pagespeed/rname/ce_-l8wrv0-x10oaQd5TPG4/http,3A/,2F112.78.1.23/phpmyadmin/js
/var/cache/mod_pagespeed/rname/ce_-l8wrv0-x10oaQd5TPG4/http,3A/,2F112.78.1.23/phpmyadmin/themes
/var/cache/mod_pagespeed/rname/ce_-l8wrv0-x10oaQd5TPG4/http,3A/,2F112.78.1.23/phpmyadmin/js/get_scripts.js.php,3Fscripts,5B,5D=common.js,26scripts,5B,5D=codemirror
/var/cache/mod_pagespeed/rname/ce_-l8wrv0-x10oaQd5TPG4/http,3A/,2F112.78.1.23/phpmyadmin/js/get_scripts.js.php,3Fscripts,5B,5D=jquery
/var/cache/mod_pagespeed/rname/ce_-l8wrv0-x10oaQd5TPG4/http,3A/,2F112.78.1.23/phpmyadmin/js/get_scripts.js.php,3Fscripts,5B,5D=common.js,26scripts,5B,5D=codemirror/lib
/var/cache/mod_pagespeed/rname/ce_-l8wrv0-x10oaQd5TPG4/http,3A/,2F112.78.1.23/phpmyadmin/js/get_scripts.js.php,3Fscripts,5B,5D=common.js,26scripts,5B,5D=codemirror/lib/codemirror.js,26scripts,5B,5D=codemirror
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can try to re-install phpmyadmin in your webserver.

Comment: I am glad that i was able to help you. hope you upvote my answer :)